# Android - Connect to socket in separate thread

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, android-asynctask, printwriter

I am trying to create a very-very simple server-client application in Android. 
The server is running on my pc, it was written in python. (just a simple while (true) loop which receives a string and responses with an other string.)
The problem is in the Android client. So i tried to create a singleton class in a separate thread, which:

- create the socket
- connect to the socket
- is reachable from other activites
- write to socket
- read from socket

I try to write and read from an other asynctask.
It is working until i try to write to the socket again. (1 write is ok, any other attempts are failed.) I do not get any exception, i checked if the socket closed or the writer null, etc. The message just not wrote to the socket.

What's wrong with this solution? :/

Could you please help me?

Here is the thread:

```
public class ConnectThread extends Thread
{
// singleton Part


private static class ThreadHolder {
    static final ConnectThread instance = new ConnectThread();
}
public static synchronized ConnectThread getInstance(){
    if(ThreadHolder.instance == null)
        Log.d("mytag", "NEW INSTANCE CREATED");
   // return (ThreadHolder.instance == null) ? ThreadHolder.instance = new ConnectThread() : ThreadHolder.instance;
    return ThreadHolder.instance;
}

private ConnectThread(){
}

// implementation part
private Socket mSocket;
private BufferedWriter socketWriter;
private BufferedReader socketReader;

public Socket getSocket() {
    return mSocket;
}


public void WriteToSocket(String msg)
{
    try{
        if(!(mSocket.isClosed()))
        {
            Log.d("mytag", "Writing to socket");
            if(socketWriter == null)
                Log.d("mytag", "Writer closed - in write to socket");
            socketWriter.write(msg);
            socketWriter.flush();
        }else
            Log.d("mytag", "CANT write to socket");
    }catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("mytag", e.toString());
    }
}

public String ReadFromSocket()
{
    try
    {
        if(!(mSocket.isClosed())) {
            Log.d("mytag", "Reading from socket");
            if(socketReader == null)
            {
                Log.d("mytag", "Reader closed - in read from socket");
            }
            return socketReader.readLine();
        }else
        {
            Log.d("mytag", "CANT from socket");
            return null;
        }
    }catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;

    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
   try
   {
       mSocket = new Socket();
       mSocket.setKeepAlive(true);
       try
       {
           mSocket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
       }
       catch (SocketException e)
       {
       }

       mSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.0.128", 8888), 2000);
       if(!(mSocket.isClosed()))
       {
           Log.d("mytag", "SOCKET IS RUNNING");
           socketWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(this.mSocket.getOutputStream()));
           socketReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.mSocket.getInputStream()));
           if(socketWriter == null)
           {
               Log.d("mytag", "WRITER NOT CREATED");
           }else
               Log.d("mytag", "WRITER READY");
           if(socketReader == null)
           {
               Log.d("mytag", "READER NOT CREATED");
           }else
               Log.d("mytag", "READER READY");
       }
   }catch (IOException e)
   {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }


}
```

}

And here are the attempts to read, write:

```
        @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        PrintDebugMsg("do in background");



        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        changeProgressMsg(progressDialog, "Checking network availability...");
        //progressDialog.setTitle("Checking network availability...");
        //check network:

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(parentContext.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if(netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected())
        {
            networkAvail = true;
            response += "| Network available |";
        }

        PrintDebugMsg("do in background 2");


        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        changeStatusImg(imgvNetworkStatus, networkAvail?R.drawable.online:R.drawable.offline);


        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        changeProgressMsg(progressDialog, "Pinging server");
        //progressDialog.setTitle("Pinging server...");


        //check server status
        try {
            PrintDebugMsg("do in background 3");


            if(!(ConnectThread.getInstance().getSocket().isClosed()))
            {

                ConnectThread.getInstance().WriteToSocket(PING_FROM_DROID);

                String line     =   "";
                line = ConnectThread.getInstance().ReadFromSocket();

                if(line.equals(PING_ACK))
                {
                    serverAvail = true;
                    response += " | pinged |";
                    PrintDebugMsg("do in background 4", true);

                }

            }
            else{
                response += " | NOT pinged |";
                PrintDebugMsg("do in background 5", true);
                throw new UnknownHostException();
            }


            PrintDebugMsg("do in background 6", true);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            response += " | UnknownHostException: " + e.toString() + " - during server check |";
            PrintDebugMsg("do in background 7", true);
        } finally{
            PrintDebugMsg("do in background 9", true);
            if(ConnectThread.getInstance().getSocket() != null){

            }
        }

        PrintDebugMsg("do in background 10", true);
        if(serverAvail)
        {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        changeStatusImg(imgvServerStatus, serverAvail?R.drawable.online:R.drawable.offline);


        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        changeProgressMsg(progressDialog, "Connectiong to server...");

        //connect to server:

        try {


            PrintDebugMsg("do in background 11",true);
            //socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);
            //socket  = ConnectThread.getInstance().getSocket();


            PrintDebugMsg("do in background 12",true);
            if(!(ConnectThread.getInstance().getSocket().isClosed())) {
                PrintDebugMsg("do in background 13",true);

                PrintDebugMsg("do in background 14",true);

                PrintDebugMsg("do in background 15",true);

                ConnectThread.getInstance().WriteToSocket(CONN_REQ_FROM_DROID);

                String line     =   "";
                line = ConnectThread.getInstance().ReadFromSocket();
                PrintDebugMsg("conn line = " + line, true);
                if(line != null && line.equals(CONN_ACK))
                {
                    connected = true;
                    response += "| connected |";
                    PrintDebugMsg("do in background 12");
                }
            }else
            {
                response += "| NOT connected |";
                PrintDebugMsg("do in background 13");
                throw new UnknownHostException();
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            response += " | UnknownHostException: " + e.toString() + " - during connecting |";
        }finally{

            PrintDebugMsg("connection finished");
            }

        if(connected) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        changeStatusImg(imgvConnectionStatus, connected?R.drawable.online:R.drawable.offline);


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------

        return null;
        }
```

The "util" functions:

```
 private void PrintDebugMsg(String msg, boolean b)
    {
        if(b)
            Log.d("mytag", msg);
    }

    private void changeProgressMsg(final ProgressDialog dialog,final String value){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                dialog.setMessage(value);
            }
        });
    }

    private void changeStatusImg(final ImageView imgView, final int imgId){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                imgView.setImageResource(imgId);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sever.java

```
public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Server().startServer();
    }

    public void startServer() {
        final ExecutorService clientProcessingPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        Runnable serverTask = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8000);
                    System.out.println("Waiting for clients to connect...");
                    while (true) {
                        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                        clientProcessingPool.submit(new ClientTask(clientSocket));
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.err.println("Unable to process client request");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        Thread serverThread = new Thread(serverTask);
        serverThread.start();

    }

    private class ClientTask implements Runnable {
        private final Socket clientSocket;

        private ClientTask(Socket clientSocket) {
            this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Got a client !");

            // Do whatever required to process the client's request

            try {
                clientSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```